# SQL query where column is value or null

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write dynamic query which should work for all scenario. where it has to pick 1 record if the param value is not null. I'm trying something like below but still it's picking all records, instead of picking 4th record.

**table**

```
idex    column1 column2 column3 column4
1       HG      null    null    null
2       HG      HD      null    null    
3       HG      H9      null    null    
4       HG      HD      H9      null

declare v1 varchar(10) = 'HG'
declare v2 varchar(10) = 'HD'
declare v3 varchar(10) = 'H9'
declare v4 varchar(10) = null


select * from table
where   (column1 is null or column1 = v1)
    and (column2 is null or column1 = v2)
    and (column3 is null or column1 = v3)
    and (column4 is null or column1 = v4)
```

Comment: MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - please correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: And if this is SQL Server your variables should begin `@`

Comment: Ideally provide the DDL+DML to create the sample data so people can test.

Comment: Your  logic here seems to be flawed. You are checking the value of column1 all for times...I have a feeling that is part of the problem. But your question is just unclear what you want as output.

Comment: I removed the conflicting mysql and sql server tags. Please edit your question and put in the tag for the DBMS you are actually using.

Comment: I believe the logic you are looking for is `where (@v1 is null or column1 = @v1) and ...`. If a filter parameter is null, any column value is accepted.  If a filter value is not null, the associated column value must match.

Comment: How did you get on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that both the column value and the variable value are null or equal e.g.

```
select *
from MyTable
where ((column1 is null and @v1 is null) or column1 = @v1)
and ((column2 is null and @v2 is null) or column2 = @v2)
and ((column3 is null and @v3 is null) or column3 = @v3)
and ((column4 is null and @v4 is null) or column4 = @v4)
```

And you need to correct your column names which were all `column1` in the compare, and assuming SQL Server your variable definitions.

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YiMIm3Tj) - note providing this in future makes it much easier for people to answer.